# parsing code with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, text-parsing

I have a text/code like this:

```
fsa sda ${kpp dsa } } sadf ${44} sda } fd sda  sd fdas ${ads}
```

I would like to build a regular expression that would find all occurrences of ${soemthing}. From the code above, the matches would be:

```
${kpp dsa } }, ${44} sda }, ${ads}
```

What I have managed to come up with is this regex "\$\s*{.*?}+", but that one unfortunately doesn't do do trick and I can't think of anything that would. Could you please help me?

Comment: You may want to use something designed for parsing rather than regular expressions.

Comment: what programming language do u use?

Comment: I use c#, but based on the other two answers, it makes no difference what language I use.

Comment: It does, actually. Because not all Regex flavors support all the existing features.

Comment: It is possible to write a regex that works for your single test case. But without a detailed specification, it is not possible to write a regex that extract the occurrences correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a non-regular language, yet you are attempting to use regular expressions.
It is best to create a parser for this!

Also, to answer you main problem: the `{` and `}` characters have a different meaning in regular expression, you should escape them with a backslash

Comment: Thank you, I will build a parser then.